Minikube mounting windows directory rm -r: "directory is part of cycle"
I'm running minikube on Windows 10 and I mount a local directory into it using Powershell:
    minikube start
    $MOUNTDIR = "C:\temp\minikube"
    Start-Process minikube -ArgumentList "mount $MOUNTDIR`:`"/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube`""

Which seems to work:
  Mounting host path C:\temp\minikube into VM as /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube ...
    ▪ Mount type:   9p
    ▪ User ID:      docker
    ▪ Group ID:     docker
    ▪ Version:      9p2000.L
    ▪ Message Size: 262144
    ▪ Options:      map[]
    ▪ Bind Address: 127.0.0.1:63682
  Userspace file server: ufs starting
✅  Successfully mounted C:\temp\minikube to /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube

Then when I ssh into Minikube and go to the directory everything seems to work fine:
$> minikube ssh
docker@minikube:~$ cd /run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube/
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ touch foo
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ ls
foo
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ rm foo
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ ls
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ mkdir foo
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ ls
foo
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ rm -r foo
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ ls

And I see the files being created in Windows explorer.
However, when I try to do something recursively I get an error:
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ mkdir -p foo/bar
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ ls
foo
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ ls foo/
bar
docker@minikube:/run/desktop/mnt/host/c/temp/minikube$ rm -r foo
rm: WARNING: Circular directory structure.
This almost certainly means that you have a corrupted file system.
NOTIFY YOUR SYSTEM MANAGER.
The following directory is part of the cycle:
  foo/bar

I can remove the directories just fine by first removing bar and then removing foo.
The same happens with other recursive operations such as chmod -R and I actually encountered the problem when trying to remove a directory from a pod using C#. But what I showed above is the mvp error reproduction.
Any clue how I can fix this?
minikube version: v1.33.1
docker version: 27.0.3
